# Attempts to create new clickable html element from JS have failed

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick

Ok, I'm attempting to create a game from scratch in HTML, but I've already hit a snag in this bit of code:

EDIT: the following takes place in the `<script>` tag.

```
var c = document.createElement("button");
                c.innerHTML = "Explore";
                c.id = "explore";
                c.onclick = "explore()";
                para.appendChild(c);
```

When the code above is executed, it creates a `<button>` element displaying "Explore", but when clicked, it doesn't run the `explore()` function. Please help.

Note: `para` refers to a `<div>` element.

I've also included the full code as a snippet, since it's short, for testing purposes.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="buttons">
   <button id="bgn", onclick="begin()">BEGIN</button>
  </div>
  <script>
   var name;
   var maxHp=10;
   var hp=10;
   var lvl=1;
   var exp=0;
   var dmg=1;
   var mp=5;
   var equip=[null,null,null,null];
   var inven=[];
   var skills=[];
   var spells=[];
   
   function begin() {
    var q = confirm("Are you sure?");
    if(q) {
     naming();
    }
   };
   function naming() {
    var q = prompt("What is your name","");
    if(q!==null) {
     name=q;
     alert("Ok, I'll call you "+name+"!");
     var para=document.getElementById("buttons");
     var child=document.getElementById("bgn");
     para.removeChild(child);
     
     var c = document.createElement("button");
     c.innerHTML = "Explore";
     c.id = "explore";
     c.onclick = "explore()";
     para.appendChild(c);
    }
   }
   function explore() {
    alert("You have explored!");
   }
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `c.addEventListener('click', explore)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your c.onclick is assigned to a string and not a function. Try it like this:

```
var c = document.createElement("button");
            c.innerHTML = "Explore";
            c.id = "explore";
            c.onclick = explore;
            para.appendChild(c);
```